# How to create MVC4 wrapper around existing/legacy classic ASP application?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, asp.net-mvc-4, proxy, legacy-app

I have a large legacy web application written in a combination of classic asp and asp.net webforms.  The client has agreed to rewrite the application and we have decided to use MVC4 but of course we don't have the time to stop support on the legacy application to build the new application.

Is there a way to put an new MVC4 wrapper application around the existing/legacy application so that parts of the legacy application can be ported to the new environment piece by piece?

Answer (score 0):

this is pretty old question, but I ran across it so thought I'd try and help out. You can still use the .aspx pages within MVC4 by modifying the routing functionality of MVC. this link should help you get started: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx